# Cover background image + gradient background

Tags: css, background-image, gradient

I'm building a website right now and trying to *set a section with background image* to cover all the section and gradient background that is generated.
I tried putting them together but it didn't really work, this is what I tried:
https://jsfiddle.net/gmtujnmh/

```css
#fullcover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  max-height: 60%;
  display: inline;
  background-image: url(http://www.materials-world.com/bricks/belden/whites/images/AlaskaWhiteVelourWT.jpg);
  /* fallback */
  background: rgba(62, 21, 49, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(62, 21, 49, 1) 0%, rgba(162, 23, 128, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(62, 21, 49, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(162, 23, 128, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(62, 21, 49, 1) 0%, rgba(162, 23, 128, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(62, 21, 49, 1) 0%, rgba(162, 23, 128, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(62, 21, 49, 1) 0%, rgba(162, 23, 128, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(62, 21, 49, 1) 0%, rgba(162, 23, 128, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#3e1531', endColorstr='#a21780', GradientType=1);
}
```

```html
<div id="fullcover"></div>
```

the gradient code it taken from cssmatic, can someone help me?

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gmtujnmh/1/) what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes but the gradient is not working

Comment: Hmmm, why gradient and full image? Do you want to play with oppacity?

Comment: if you want to cover the entire screen just remove max-height

Comment: exaclty,the problem is im working on wordpress website and i cant make another section or a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from your fiddle doesn't match the code you posted here, this answer is for the code in the fiddle.

You need to add some opacity to the gradient, it solved it for me, here a fiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/gmtujnmh/2/

```
#fullcover{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    max-height: 60%;
    display:inline;

    background-image: url(http://www.materials-world.com/bricks/belden/whites/images/AlaskaWhiteVelourWT.jpg); /* fallback */

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(62,21,49,.6)),
  to(rgba(162,23,128,.9)), color-stop(.5,#333333)
), url(http://www.materials-world.com/bricks/belden/whites/images/AlaskaWhiteVelourWT.jpg); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
```

Now you only need to play with the colors and opacity to get what you want, hope it helps.

Comment: Another question, can i tell my background image where to begin?

Comment: You can move the background image with the background-position property  by using pixels, keywords or percentages... If you want something different than this you should probably do some research and see if there is something useful, if there's not you can always create a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
  body{
      background:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Googlelogo1997.jpg") no-repeat center center, linear-gradient(green, blue);
    height:100%;
    }
    html{height:100%;}
```

```html
  

    <body>
    here we go
    </body>
```